# how can I split up this string

Tags: bash, awk, gnu, cut

I am currently trying to sanitize some log files so they are in an easier format to read, and have been trying to use the gnu cut command, which works fairly well, although I cannot really think of a good way to remove the [INFO] part of the string

```
logs/logs/server_1283258036.log:2010-08-31 23:06:51 [INFO] <NateMar> where?!
logs/logs/server_1281904775.log:2010-08-15 22:59:53 [INFO] <BoonTheMoon> Â§b<BoonTheMoon>Â§ohhhhhh
logs/logs/server_1282136782.log:2010-08-18 16:27:32 [INFO] <pinguin> <pinguin>Â§F :/
logs/logs/server_1282136782.log:2010-08-18 16:27:37 [INFO] <TotempaaltJ> <TotempaaltJ>Â§F That helped A LOT
logs/logs/server_1282136782.log:2010-08-18 16:27:37 [INFO] <Rizual> Â§b<Rizual>Â§F hm?
logs/logs/server_1282136782.log:2010-08-18 16:29:10 [INFO] <pinguin> <pinguin>Â§F bah
logs/logs/server_1282136782.log:2010-08-18 16:29:35 [INFO] <TotempaaltJ> <TotempaaltJ>Â§F Finished my houses 
logs/logs/server_1282136782.log:2010-08-18 16:29:40 [INFO] <TotempaaltJ> <TotempaaltJ>Â§F or whatever
logs/logs/server_1282136782.log:2010-08-18 16:30:47 [INFO] <Rizual> Â§b<Rizual>Â§So much iron
logs/logs/server_1282136782.log:2010-08-18 16:30:58 [INFO] <TotempaaltJ> <TotempaaltJ>Â§F Ah yes, furnaces don't work.o
logs/logs/server_1282136782.log:2010-08-18 16:31:01 [INFO] <Rizual> Â§b<Rizual>Â§F They do
logs/logs/server_1282136782.log:2010-08-18 16:31:06 [INFO] <TotempaaltJ> <TotempaaltJ>Â§F Hm
logs/logs/server_1282136782.log:2010-08-18 16:31:08 [INFO] <Rizual> Â§b<Rizual>Â§F just need to use /lighter
logs/logs/server_1282136782.log:2010-08-18 16:31:12 [INFO] <Valrix> <Valrix>Â§FNotch fixed them?
```

I would ultimately want to get the strings down to something that resembles the following (keep in mind that the logs are in two formats, the older format which has 2 copies of the names, as can be seen in the bulk of the logs above, and also the newer format, which only has the name in there once (can be seen in the first log line, the `<natemar>` one))

```
2010-08-31 23:06:51 <NateMar> where?!    
2010-08-15 22:59:53 <BoonTheMoon> ohhhhhh (this one would require both the same editing as above, plus removal of the "extra" name Â§b<BoonTheMoon>Â§)
```

How should I go about doing this? Have thought about using awk, although I'm having a difficult time getting a grip on how that would work, so not sure how to set up something to do that. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I just noticed the `Â§b` and `Â§ohhhhhh`, are those really part of the log data, or some artifact from copy-paste?. Also, are the number of fields in your data consistent? Usually log data will be, but I'm sure there are exceptions.

Comment: @Levon those are color codes that are interpreted by a client, also yep they are consistent, just grabbed two random lines as an example, the log files themselves amount to around 4gb of text files, would need some way to organize them :)

Comment: So the number of fields separated by white-space may vary from line to line? And you do want the last field on the first line, but not on the 2nd line of your sample data?

Comment: @Levon they may very a little, although really the only place they would very would be after the name, <NateMar> for instance, everything to the left of that would be chat which would not need to be edited at all, also if possible, it would be neat if there was a way to remove the extra "name" from the second field, that was part of an older log format, the top line is the newer format which does not display the name twice, so ideally something along the lines of 2010-08-15 22:59:53 <BoonTheMoon> ohhhhhh instead of 2010-08-15 22:59:53 <BoonTheMoon> Â§b<BoonTheMoon>Â§ohhhhhh

Comment: It's probably a good idea to update your post with the specific information in the comment above. Also, you'd have to provide more detailed information about these color codes if you want the fields between them to be filtered out. I.e., is there a fixed sequence that starts/ends them, a range of valid values,  etc. This additional info makes this a more challenging problem due to these fields and the variable lines.

Comment: @Levon have gone ahead and edited the original post, have also added a section of the logs too (the older log form that included the extra name with the color codes) to better show what format they follow. The color codes themselves can be any of the following (§0 §1 §2 §3 §4 §5 §6 §7 §8 §9 §a §b §c §d §e §f), and they will always be directly next to the second/copied player name, if there is not anything that could be done about those though, thats not a problem as you guys have already been an immense help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More takes on this, in sed, awk and bash:

```
[ghoti@pc ~]$ cat text
logs/logs/server_1283258036.log:2010-08-31 23:06:51 [INFO] <NateMar> where?!
logs/logs/server_1281904775.log:2010-08-15 22:59:53 [INFO] <BoonTheMoon> Â§b<BoonTheMoon>Â§ohhhhhh

[ghoti@pc ~]$ sed 's/^[^:]*://;s/[[][^]]*[]] //' text
2010-08-31 23:06:51 <NateMar> where?!
2010-08-15 22:59:53 <BoonTheMoon> Â§b<BoonTheMoon>Â§ohhhhhh

[ghoti@pc ~]$ awk '{sub(/^[^:]+:/,""); $3=""} 1' text
2010-08-31 23:06:51  <NateMar> where?!
2010-08-15 22:59:53  <BoonTheMoon> Â§b<BoonTheMoon>Â§ohhhhhh

[ghoti@pc ~]$ while read line; do line=${line#*:}; echo "${line/\[*\] }"; done < text
2010-08-31 23:06:51 <NateMar> where?!
2010-08-15 22:59:53 <BoonTheMoon> Â§b<BoonTheMoon>Â§ohhhhhh
```

While these are simple, they may be imperfect for the sake of shortness.  For example, the awk script, by eliminating the third "word", leaves spaces that delimit the now-null word.

Note that as "elegant" as one-liners may seem for quick jobs, it's usually a better idea to be explicit with your code, especially when you have to deal with unknown input data or if you won't be inspecting your results immediately after you run things.

This is harder to read, but could be much safer, depending on your input:

```
[ghoti@pc ~]$ awk '$3~/^[[].+[]]$/{$3="";sub(/  /," ")} {sub(/^[^:]+:/,"")} 1' text
2010-08-31 23:06:51 <NateMar> where?!
2010-08-15 22:59:53 <BoonTheMoon> ÃÂ§b<BoonTheMoon>ÃÂ§ohhhhhh
```

For the bash script, you'd be safer to use a character class rather than a glob:

```
[ghoti@pc ~]$ shopt -s extglob
[ghoti@pc ~]$ while read line; do line=${line#*:}; echo "${line/\[+([[:upper:]])\] /}"; done < text
2010-08-31 23:06:51 <NateMar> where?!
2010-08-15 22:59:53 <BoonTheMoon> ÃÂ§b<BoonTheMoon>ÃÂ§ohhhhhh
```

Note that the `extglob` shopt option lets you use more advanced pattern matching inside the parameter replacement pattern.  `man bash` and look for `Pathname Expansion` for details.

**UPDATE:**

You've added a new requirement to your question that wasn't there originally.  Here's how you can achieve your new requirement with awk:

```
awk '$3~/^[[].+[]]$/{$3="";sub(/  /," ")} {sub(/^[^:]+:/,"")} $3~/^<.+>$/{sub(/^(Â§b)?<[[:alpha:]]+>Â§/,"",$4)} 1' text
```

This simply removes coloured nicknames from the 4th string, if the 3rd string looks like a bracketed nickname.  This works for the sample you posted, but only you can determine whether this will work for you.

And with bash:

```
shopt -s extglob
while read date time tag nick line; do
  printf "%s %s %s %s\n" "${date#*:}" "$time" "$nick" "${line/#*([^< ])$nick??}"
done < text
```

Answer (score 3):

You're on the right track using the `cut` command. The key to removing the [INFO] field is to exclude it from the final output. The  `-f1,2,4-` argument does just that by including all fields *except* the 3rd which is just [INFO] at that point.

```sh
cut -d: -f2- Input.txt | cut -d' ' -f1,2,4- > Output.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

(potentially pending revision based on answer to the question posted in the comment above)

Using [`awk`](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html):

```
awk '{sub(".log:", ".log "); print $2, $3, $5, $6}' data.txt
```

will give you:

```
2010-08-31 23:06:51 <NateMar> where?!
2010-08-15 22:59:53 <BoonTheMoon> Â§b<BoonTheMoon>Â§ohhhhhh
```

*Explanation*:

I changed the `:` after "`.log:`" to a blank and then was able to separate the fields in the line by white-space. The fields you were interested in were 2, 3, 5 and 6 so I printed them out with `awk` by using `$` to get the content of each field on the line.

Note that you can also use `printf` to format the data more precisely if that's needed.

Comment: This fails on lines with extra words.  Wouldn't it make more sense simply to remove the filename prefix entirely with `sub("^[^:]+.log:", "");` ?

Answer (score 1):

With `sed` it could be done more demostrably:

```
$> cat ./text
logs/logs/server_1283258036.log:2010-08-31 23:06:51 [INFO] <NateMar> where?!
logs/logs/server_1281904775.log:2010-08-15 22:59:53 [INFO] <BoonTheMoon> Â§b<BoonTheMoon>Â§ohhhhhh

$> sed -r -e 's/^.*log:([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}\ )([0-9\ \:]*\ )(\[[A-Z]*\]\ )(.*)$/\1\2\4/' ./text
2010-08-31 23:06:51 <NateMar> where?!
2010-08-15 22:59:53 <BoonTheMoon> Â§b<BoonTheMoon>Â§ohhhhhh
```

Whole idea is to match some fields of log string and then leave only ones you need.